# Best way of authenticate player, via http or socket?

Tags: c#, php, sockets, unity-game-engine

Hi i'm making a game in Unity and i'd like to know whats more reasonable if it's making the auth server in PHP (using my CodeIgniter to handle multi season) and gather information via web or if i should use via socket and send a packet for auth server open a http request, gather info and register the client if he's going to login. 
What's more professional by doing so?

Comment: auth2 if like standards...

Comment: you mean oauth2? idk concretly what would you prefer for a game auth, php sessions or socket handling a constant connection.

Comment: I meant oauth2. The question about socket depends on the type of game and how many players connected at a time. You will aget the most performance with socket.

Comment: Well will be a game witch will be only opening a match and you play but you only need constant connection in-game, in menus you dont so that's why im quite confused what i should use

Comment: php for authentication, socket for game play. you can do both with socket but how i mentioned is how most people do this

Comment: So basically i request oauth and open a session with encrypted data, after i retrieve it and when i need while his online untill disconnect and break over the oauth session i gather from that secure tunnel?

Comment: You send username/password to the server. php will login, do some oauth stuff and generate a key. You store this key on the server then send that key back to Unity. Unity will then be able to perform actions on the server by making more requests with that key you received from server

Comment: Actually i'm doing it but without oauth just session and sha encrypt for data to identify but i'm using session id but i'll change to oauth.